# C++/CLI .ToString() compilation fails in generic class for enum types: error C2228: left of '.ToString' must have class/struct/union

Tags: visual-studio, generics, enums, c++-cli, managed

Simply create a CLR console application in Visual Studio for C++ and copy this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

generic <typename TEnumMgd>
where TEnumMgd : value class, System::ValueType, System::IConvertible
public ref class EnumerationGenericClass
{
public:
    EnumerationGenericClass(TEnumMgd value)
    {
        String^ text = value.ToString(); // Cannot compile
    }
};

public enum class Test{ Foo, Bar };

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    auto obj = gcnew EnumerationGenericClass<Test>(Test::Foo);
    return 0;
}
```

This fails with "error C2228: left of '.ToString' must have class/struct/union", but why and how can this be resolved? Preferably without any boxing.

UPDATE: Changed format to separate question and answer.

Comment: value->ToString() is the proper syntax, you want to call a method implemented by System::Object, a reference type.  You get Opcodes.Constrained instead of Opcodes.Box in the MSIL, as you desire.  Have a look-see with ildasm.exe

Comment: I am guessing this is because this was the only general way to make this generic in C++. In C# this is not a problem because the accessor is always ".". In C++ the acessor is either "." or "->" depending on it is value or ref type. For a generic the type can be both so I guess they had to choose and thus selected "->" as default.

Comment: @HansPassant well I do not want to call ToString() on object, but the value type equivalent, but this is what happens in the IL so that is fine. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

This can compile if you instead write:

```
        String^ text = value->ToString();
```

That is, C++/CLI uses the "->" accessor for generic types no matter what. However, the IL that is output for the ctor is seen below, so it is not boxed but constrained to be a value type as expected.

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void  .ctor(!TEnumMgd 'value') cil managed
{
  // Code size       29 (0x1d)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals ([0] string text)
  IL_0000:  ldnull
  IL_0001:  stloc.0
  IL_0002:  ldarg.0
  IL_0003:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_0008:  ldarga.s   'value'
  IL_000a:  constrained. !TEnumMgd
  IL_0010:  callvirt   instance string [mscorlib]System.ValueType::ToString()
  IL_0015:  stloc.0
  IL_0016:  ldloc.0
  IL_0017:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_001c:  ret
} // end of method EnumerationGenericClass`1::.ctor
```